# How do you use the /setblock command to place down more than one layer of snow

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

The `/setblock` command can place the snow layer block like so, `/setblock ~ ~ ~ snow_layer`, but how do you increase how many layers are placed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top snow/snow layers use their [data value](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snow#Block_data) to store how many layers it is. Data value 0 is 1 layer, data value 1 is 2 layers and so on until data value 7 is 8 layers.

To use this in a `setblock`command you would use `/setblock x y z snow_layer [data value]`.

Comment: thank you! Your answer is a big help

Comment: @herobrine37 You're welcome! You can also [accept this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the green checkmark, which indicates that this answer solved your question. It also gives both of us some [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: is there anything i can answer for you? I know a lot about commands!

Comment: @herobrine37 No. However, there are plenty of [unanswered questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-commands?sort=MostVotes&filters=NoAnswers&edited=true) with the tag [tag:minecraft-commands] that you can answer.